# How to find the $E(X|\mathcal{G})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The question is:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P) = ([0,1], R_{[0,1]},m)$ where $R_{[0,1]}$ is the $\sigma$-field of Borel subsets of the (closed) unit interval $[0,1]$, and $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the $\sigma$-field generated by the events $[0,1/3]$,$(1/3, 2/3]$, and $(2/3,1].$ Define the random variable $X$ on $\Omega$ by $X(w)=w^2$.
Find $E(X|\mathcal{G})$.

My attempt is:

The $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{G} = \{\phi, [0,1/3] , (1/3,2/3] \cup (2/3,1]~,(1/3,2/3],~[0,1/3]\cup (2/3,1],~(2/3,1],~[0,1/3] \cup (1/3,2/3],~[0,1]\}$.

In the question, $X(w)=w^2$, and I need to find a random variable $Y$ such that $E(X|\mathcal{G})=Y$ if

i) $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.
ii) for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$, then $\int_{A} X(w) dw = \int_{A} Y(w) dw $.

Then I calculate the integration over the each element of $\mathcal{G}$ and I got $Y(w)=w^2$.

Is this a correct solution of this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't methods to find the conditional expectation in the general case and you have to guess it. That being said, the obvious guess is to take $Y = \sum_{k = 1}^K c_k \mathbf{1}_{A_k},$ where $A_k$ is the disjoint set that generate $\mathscr{G}$ and the $c_k$ are the average of $X$ on $A_k$ (assuming $P(A_k) > 0,$ we get $c_k = E(X \mid A_k)$ and if $P(A_k) = 0,$ then it doesn't matter what $c_k$ is).

Comment: @WilliamM. That is the general result for when $\mathcal{G}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a countable partition of $\Omega$.

Comment: @WilliamM. do you mean if I take $A_2 = [0,1/3]$ then $E(X|A_2) = (1/3)^4=c_2$. Similarly, I will find $c_k$ over each element of $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: $E(X \mid 0 \leq X \leq 1/3) = \dfrac{\int_0^{1/3} x^2 f_X(x)dx }{\int_0^{1/3} f_X} = 3 \times (1/3) (1/3)^3 = 1/27.$

Comment: @Mason sure, this is a general result but when I saw it, it was a guess. In fact, I have never seen a compelling argument as to _why_ (a natural derivation perhaps) this is the right choice, rather just give it and show it is (a.k.a. guessing the solution).

Comment: @WilliamM. could you please let me know what is the density function $f_X$ you get in this question?